# Arduino Serial Monitor and Display lag

Tags: c#, arduino, hardware, display

I am having a bit of an issue with my Arduino Project.

Essentially what I am making is a hardware monitor that displays temperature, clock speed, fan speed etc.

I am doing this by sending the values of the clock speed and temps etc. to the arduino via the serial monitor. The arduino reads those values and puts in on the display

The issue is the following. It reads the serial output fine without a problem. But displaying it doesnt work properly. It takes the arduino forever to load in the values on the display and updating it takes 10-15s when I want it to be 1s.

Could it be that the value names that C# sends to Arduino are too long so it takes too much time and processing power to do all of this in a short amount of time??

Also the less values I let the arduino display on the screen the faster it becomes.

Ill show you the Arduino serial monitor and display code below (Yes I could be making a lot of mistakes, I just started Arduino 4 months ago)

Serial Monitor:

```
void RefreshAllValues()
{
  static bool isBuffering = false;
  int CPUL;
  int GPUL;
  int RAMT;
  int RAMA;
  int CPUC;
  int GPUC;
  int GPUMC;
  int CPUT;
  int GPUT;
  static String IncomingMessage = "";

  if (Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    char IncomingChar = (char)Serial.read();
    if (IncomingChar == '#')
    {
      isBuffering = true;
      IncomingMessage = "";
    }
    if (IncomingChar == '*')
    {
      isBuffering = false;
      IncomingMessage += IncomingChar;
      if (IncomingMessage.startsWith("#CPU_LOAD:"))
      {
        int dv = IncomingMessage.indexOf(":");
        CPUL = IncomingMessage.substring(dv + 1).toInt();
        CPULoad = String(CPUL) + "%";
        IncomingMessage = "";
      }
      else if (IncomingMessage.startsWith("#GPU_LOAD:"))
      {
        int dv = IncomingMessage.indexOf(":");
        GPUL = IncomingMessage.substring(dv + 1).toInt();
        GPULoad = String(GPUL) + "%";
        IncomingMessage = "";
      }
      else if (IncomingMessage.startsWith("#TOTAL_RAM:"))
      {
        int dv = IncomingMessage.indexOf(":");
        RAMT = IncomingMessage.substring(dv + 1).toInt();
        RAMTotal = String(RAMT) + "MB";
        IncomingMessage = "";
      }
      else if (IncomingMessage.startsWith("#AVAILABLE_RAM:"))
      {
        int dv = IncomingMessage.indexOf(":");
        RAMA = IncomingMessage.substring(dv + 1).toInt();
        RAMAvailable =  String(RAMA) + "MB";
        IncomingMessage = "";
      }
      else if (IncomingMessage.startsWith("#GPU_CLOCK:"))
      {
        int dv = IncomingMessage.indexOf(":");
        GPUC = IncomingMessage.substring(dv + 1).toInt();
        GPUClock = String(GPUC) + "Mhz";
        IncomingMessage = "";
      }
      else if (IncomingMessage.startsWith("#GPU_MEMORY_CLOCK:"))
      {
        int dv = IncomingMessage.indexOf(":");
        GPUMC = IncomingMessage.substring(dv + 1).toInt();
        GPUMemory = String(GPUMC) + "Mhz";
        IncomingMessage = "";
      }
      else if (IncomingMessage.startsWith("#CPU_CLOCK:"))
      {
        int dv = IncomingMessage.indexOf(":");
        CPUC = IncomingMessage.substring(dv + 1).toInt();
        CPUClock =  String(CPUC) + "Mhz";
        IncomingMessage = "";
      }
      else if (IncomingMessage.startsWith("#CPU_TEMP:"))
      {
        int dv = IncomingMessage.indexOf(":");
        CPUT = IncomingMessage.substring(dv + 1).toInt();
        CPUTemp = String(CPUT) + "C";
        IncomingMessage = "";
      }
      else if (IncomingMessage.startsWith("#GPU_TEMP:"))
      {
        int dv = IncomingMessage.indexOf(":");
        GPUT = IncomingMessage.substring(dv + 1).toInt();
        GPUTemp = String(GPUT) + "C";
        IncomingMessage = "";
      }

    }
    if (isBuffering)
    {
      IncomingMessage += IncomingChar;
    }
  }
}
```

Displaying it on the screen:

```
 tft.setFont(Terminal6x8);
  RefreshAllValues();
  delay(10); //Otherwise it skips the 1st value that comes through
  tft.drawText(30, 10, "CPU");
  tft.drawText(130, 10, "GPU");
  tft.drawText(30, 20, CPULoad);
  tft.drawText(30, 40, CPUClock);  
  tft.drawText(130, 20, GPUTemp);
  tft.drawText(130, 40, GPUClock);
  tft.drawText(130, 60, GPULoad);
  tft.drawText(75, 85, RAMAvailable);
```

I basically don't know how to fix this issue and searching on how to set an interval of 5s between serial reads didn't give me any helpful results..

I hope someone can help me with this
Thanks

Comment: Why do you convert to int and back to string again? Also, there is a lot of code duplication which could be handled in a method. But none of which should cause the perceived effect.

Comment: You are reading a single character from the serial only every 10 ms +time to draw to the LCD.